# Bulk Remove User Emails within Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I've hit a bit of a wall trying to figure out how to bulk remove old emails within Netsuite (ie. transactions emailed to clients, statements, etc...).

I have over 40,000 emails taking up way to much storage space within NS.

Can't seem to do it via `Workflow` or `Mass Update` etc...

Is there a simplistic method I'm missing? Or am I going to *have* to write some suitescript to do it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a Mass Delete Script before which works great on other records.  I haven't used it on messages, but I did confirm that you can deploy it on messages so it should be good.  Steps to use it are:

1. Install bundle 18108.
2. Create script deployment for the record type you want to delete (Message in your case)
3. Go to Mass Updates and expand Custom Updates.  You should see Mass_Delete_Script in there under Message.
4. Create mass update as you usually would - TAKING EXTRA CARE NOT TO CLICK "PERFORM UPDATE" UNLESS YOU'RE ABSOLUTELY SURE YOU'RE SEARCH IS CORRECT!  Beware that you can of course cause a lot of grief very quickly with a tool like this.  On the other hand you can save a lot of time too :)